# Defining dtype of df.to_sparse() result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which is sparse and for memory efficiency I wish to convert it using `to_sparse()`

However it seems that the new representation ends up with the `dtype=float64`, even when my `df` is `dtype=int8`.

Is there a way specify the data type/ prevent auto conversion to `dtype=float64` when using `to_sparse()` ?

Answer (score 1):

## In short. No.

You see, dtypes is not a pandas controlled entity. **Dtypes is typically a numpy thing.**
Dtypes are not controllable in any way, they are *automagically asserted* by numpy and can only change when you change the data inside the dataframe or numpy array.

That being said, the typical reason for ending up with a float instead of an int as a dtype is because of the introduction of NaN values into the series or numpy array. This is a pandas gotcha some say. I personally would argue it is due to the (too) close coupling between pandas and numpy.

In general, dtypes should never be trusted for anything, they are incredibly unreliable. I think everyone working with numpy/pandas would live a better life if they were never exposed to dtypes at all.

If you really really hate floats, the only other option for you as far as I know is to use string representations, which of course causes even more problems in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant explanation. I was wondering: "the typical reason for ending up with a float instead of an int as a dtype is because of the introduction of NaN values into the series or numpy array", if I use `df.fillna(0).to_sparse(fillvalue=0)` I avoid ending up with NaN values. This does not however solve the problem. Did I miss to read between the lines from your explanation?

Comment: numpy does not automagically change a dtype float to dtype int because there are no NaN values in it. Obviously there have been NaN values at some point in the .to_sparse() transformation. You can try to add an `.astype(int)` in the end, it will change the dtypes to int, but it is yet another step which will cost you performance.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Looking under the hood, the `Pandas` sparse frame implementation at `pandas.sparse.frame` we see that the `astype()` method is still waiting to be implemented as of release 0.18.0. [Ref. Github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/sparse/frame.py)

When we have some implementation in place, conversion of `dtype` should work like `pandas.core.frame` (Pandas `DataFrame`). Given a Pandas `DataFrame` `df` we could convert it to `SparseDataFrame` and specify `dtype`

```
df.to_sparse().astype(dtype)
```

ATM, `SparseDataFrame` does not have much support for `dtype` but it is currently being developed. Refer this issue that I opened [Github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13001).